# How to place a hyperlink field in a web page at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, location, hyperlink

I am trying to display contents of a folder in a hyperlink. I am using masterpage also. The hyperlinks are not shown into the content page. what to do for that?

I know in windows forms we can use like
TextBox.Location=new Point(100,100);

But how to do in web page...please anybody suggest me..

my coding in page_load is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/ProjectsUpload"));
    int i = 0;
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        HyperLink HL = new HyperLink();
        HL.ID = "HyperLink" + i++;
        HL.Text = fi.Name;
        HL.NavigateUrl = "downloading.aspx?file=" + fi.Name;
        Page.Controls.Add(HL);
        Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick at a glance. Couple of debug questions: 1) Do you definitely go round that loop? 2) If you try to add a static link (ie without all the FS access) then does that work? 3) Does the page source show anything at all where you expect these to appear? Coudl they be appearing in the wrong place and they are being hidden or something...

Answer (score 2):

You can't add it directly to `Page.Controls`. You have to add it to the `ContentPlaceHolder` on the page.

Comment: ContentPlaceHolder? According to me it should be a PlaceHolder control instead.

Comment: @XIII - He can use a PlaceHolder too, as long as it's inside of a ContentPlaceHolder.  Since he's using a Master Page, anything he wants visible will need to be in one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dynamically creating controls, which is rather messy and error-prone, have you considered using an `asp:Repeater` control and binding the files directly to it? Something like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterFiles" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
            NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("downloading.aspx?file={0}", Container.DataItem)%>' />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and in code behind:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/ProjectsUpload"));
RepeaterFiles.DataSource = di.GetFiles();
RepeaterFiles.DataBind();
```

That way you can use declarative mark-up to control layout and keep the logic in your code-behind.

Comment: Hi Dan Thanks for your suggestion. I will try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Put a PlaceHolder control on your page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph" />
```

In your code behind write like:

```
HyperLink HL = new HyperLink();
HL.ID = "HyperLink" + i++;
HL.Text = fi.Name;
HL.NavigateUrl = "downloading.aspx?file=" + fi.Name;
ph.Controls.Add(HL);
ph.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>"});
```

I'm making use of the newly C# 3 feature on that last line to set the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the debugger to step through the loop to verify that it processes at least one file?

Instead of adding the links to `Page.Controls`, you could put a list control on the page, and then add each link within a list item.  Then you'd know precisely where on the page they should appear.

Comment: Hi carl thanks for your suggestion. My point is if I am not using masterpage i can see the hyperlinks. But if I use masterpage links are not shown. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Panel or a Label in the Page's Content area, and add your HyperLinks into the Controls collection of the Panel.

(Stepping through the code to check whether the IIS App actually enumerates any files in the directory would help too.)